# snmp4j map table to pojo

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I have a pojo like this :

```
public class IpAddress {
    private String index ;
    private String ip ;
    private String netmask ;
    // Getter & Setter ....
}
```

now i wrote a code with snmp4j for fetch table and map result to list of this pojo :

```
public class MainClass {
    private static final Address address = GenericAddress.parse("udp://10.10.10.2/161");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CommunityTarget<Address> target = new CommunityTarget<>();
        target.setCommunity(new OctetString("private"));
        target.setAddress(address);
        target.setRetries(5);
        target.setTimeout(15000);
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);

        List<IpAddress> ipAddressList = doWalkTable(".1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20", target);

        System.out.println(ipAddressList);
    }
    public static List<IpAddress> doWalkTable(String tableOid, Target<Address> target) throws IOException {
        List<IpAddress> ipAddressList = new ArrayList<>();
        TransportMapping<? extends Address> transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);
        transport.listen();

        TableUtils tableUtils = new TableUtils(snmp, new DefaultPDUFactory());
        List<TableEvent> events = tableUtils.getTable(target, new OID[]{new OID(tableOid)}, null, null);
        if (events == null || events.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Unable to read table...");
            return ipAddressList;
        }

        for (TableEvent event : events) {
            if (event == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (event.isError()) {
                System.out.println("Error: table OID [" + tableOid + "] " + event.getErrorMessage());
                continue;
            }

            VariableBinding[] varBindings = event.getColumns();

            if (varBindings == null || varBindings.length == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            for (VariableBinding varBinding : varBindings) {
                if (varBinding == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // -> How can fill ipAddressList ????
            }
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");

        }
        snmp.close();
        return ipAddressList;
    }
}
```

this is result of snmptable :

```
# snmptable -v 2c -c public 10.10.10.2 IP-MIB::ipAddrTable
  
  ipAdEntAddr ipAdEntIfIndex ipAdEntNetMask ipAdEntBcastAddr ipAdEntReasmMaxSize
  10.10.10.2              2  255.255.255.0                1               18024
  115.54.20.12            4  255.255.255.0                1               18024
```

My problem is :
**1)** there is any solution to find out OID is table or tree ?
**2)** I can not understand how can detect row and columns from TableEvent .
result does not have any identifier for calculate number of rows or number of columns .

Answer (score 0):

Typically oids that end with a .0 are part of a tree, while oid that do not end with a .0 are part of a table

To better understand tables

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.xxx.xxx.1 will denote the start of a table.
1.3.6.1.4.1.xxx.xxx.1.1.1 will denote a column entry.
1.3.6.1.4.1.xxx.xxx.1.1.1.2 will denote a row entry.
```

Given the table:

```
 |a|b|c|
1
2
3
```

You can expect to find value at column B row 3 at oid address
1.3.6.1.4.1.xxx.xxx.1.1.2.3